# insert multiple integers in a column of my table in mysql using nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database

I'm new in node and mysql and i'm trying to create orders in which I indicate the products I want to include and indicate the user associated with the order.

I am probably complicating my life.  But...

The situation is this:

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products(
  id_product int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name_product text unique,
  primary key(id_product)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
  id_user int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name_user text,
  surname_user text,
  email_user text unique,
  primary key(id_user)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders(
  number_order int not null,
  id_order int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
  date_order timestamp,
  id_product int not null,
  id_user int not null,
  primary key(number_order),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_product) REFERENCES products(id_product),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_user) REFERENCES users(id_user)
);
```

result:

[image: tables]

`id_product` and `id_user` of the `orders` table are mutually related to the `products` and `users` tables.

How can I do this? How can I insert multiple products into one order, which in turn is associated with one user? I can't reason with this

This is the result. It doesn't seem like the right way to run the system to me.

[image]

Comment: You should properly _normalize_ your data model first. You should have an additional `OrderPosition` table or something, in which you record the individual order positions. Connection to the order table via the `id_order` id in there.

Comment: You might consider the OrderHeader and OrderLine concept

Comment: @CBroe Could you please elaborate on reading what you wrote? i didn't quite understand
Thank you in advance

Comment: You should have one table for your orders - into that goes the order date, and the user. (Which you are currently redundantly repeating, in every record.) And then you have another table for your order _items_ - which product got ordered & in which quantity. Plus the order id, referring to the order in the order table.

Comment: If the keyword _normalization_ relating to databases & data modeling doesn't mean anything to you yet, then you should go read up on that first of all now. (Otherwise, you'll be fixing a lot of stuff later on.)